# what is the difference between nginx $upstream_status and $status

Tags: nginx

Is $upstream_status represents the status code returned by the upstream server to nginx, and $status represents the status code returned by the nginx server to the client？
I tried to read the official documents but I am not sure if i misunderstood the explanation of $status in ngx_http_core_module.